# Pedigree Probability of Autosomal Recessive Trait

Tags: genetics, homework, genetic-diagrams

Here is a pedigree:

[image: Pedigree Chart]

The trait is autosomal recessive.

The question is:  What is the probability that the bottom 2 people (4 and 5) have a child with the trait?

I tried doing `2/3 * 2/3 * 2/3 *1/4` and got `2/27` but this is wrong. I thought that the probability of III 1 being a carrier is 2/3.  The probability that IV 4 is a carrier is also 2/3.  The probability that III 6 is a carrier is 2/3 and IV 5 must be a carrier.  So IV 4 and IV 5 must be carriers.  The probability that they have a child with the trait is 1/4. But I am not getting the right answer.

The right answer is 1/6.

Comment: You have now got sufficient rep to avoid new user restrictions so can post inline images yourself - you can either do this manually using [markdown](http://biology.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) or there is a button on the WYSIWYG editor :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with the left hand side of the diagram:

- *III:2* is definitely a carrier (Tt) as one parent (*II:2*) is affected (tt).
- *III:1* is also definitely a carrier (Tt) as when mating with *III:2* they produce an affected (tt) offspring (*IV:1*)
- This means that we can work out the possibilities for *IV:4* as we know the parent genotypes.  It follows the standard arrangement for two carrier parents giving the options of:

  - TT (1/4)
  - Tt (2/4 = 1/2)
  - tt (Normally 1/4 but in this case 0 as individual not marked as affected).
- Therefore for this scenario, the probabilities for *IV:4* are :

  - TT (1/3)
  - Tt (2/3)

Now if we look at the right hand side of the diagram.

- *IV:5* is definitely a carrier (Tt) as one of their parents (*III:5*) is affected.

This gives two possible Punnett squares to be examined:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                        ♂ (IV:5)                               |
|                          T                                   t                |
|            -------------------------------------------------------------------|
|           |                                |                                  |
|         T |              TT                |                Tt                |
|           |                                |                                  |
| (IV:4)    |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    ♀      |                                |                                  |
|         T |              TT                |                Tt                |
|           |                                |                                  |
|-----------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

This gives nil affected offspring so we can disregard this option for your question (as we are ONLY looking for scenarios which produce affected individuals).

Therefore the alternative is:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                        ♂ (IV:5)                               |
|                          T                                   t                |
|            -------------------------------------------------------------------|
|           |                                |                                  |
|         T |              TT                |                Tt                |
|           |                                |                                  |
| (IV:4)    |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    ♀      |                                |                                  |
|         t |              TT                |                tt                |
|           |                                |                                  |
|-----------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Giving 1/4 affected offspring.

As mentioned above, in order to have affected offspring then *IV:4* **must** be Tt.  There is a `2/3` chance of this being the case.  If this is the case, then there is a `1/4` chance of the child being tt.

**Both** conditions need to be true for this to happen so we multiply the fractions:

```
2/3 * 1/4 = 1/6
```